# Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: __BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) when deleting

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime-error, sdl, sdl-2

My friend and I were updating our Tetris like project to be more dynamic (allow any size shapes instead of only 4 tiled shapes), upgrading from arrays to vectors. Everything worked fine before but now we get the error from the title whenever a shape reaches the floor. This is the exact line of code where it happens (the delete[] currentShape):

```
main.cpp

    if (currentShape != NULL) {
        delete[] currentShape; // Breaks here
    }
    currentShape = new Shape;
```

The whole project is a bit long so here it is on Pastebin:

- [main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/ybYbf4fw) (The break's on line 853)
- [shape.h and shape.cpp](http://pastebin.com/JfJ2dM48)

EDIT: It also breaks on line 167 if you hold it since it has the same code, but it shouldn't have anything to do with the bug.

Comment: `delete[] currentShape; // Breaks here` Was currentShape already deleted?

Comment: Your functions are way to long, plus I doubt your error has anything to do with `vector`.  You are still dynamically allocating memory using `new`, so more than likely you always had a bug, just that the program has changed enough to now expose it.

Comment: @drescherjm currentShape is only deleted in that line of code and it's replaced instantly afterwards so no. The only time it would be NULL is when the program starts, and then it gets set. Also, when it breaks, the VS Autos tab shows that currentShape exists and is normal.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do you think it's worth making new functions even if I only call them once for more organization? That might be useful to make my code less clustered though. Also, if what you said is right, what can I do? Thanks!

Comment: @SwissAndOr Your allocation and deallocation of `currentShape` are so far away from each other and occur in multiple places.   I just did a search for `new ` in your main.cpp, and I see two places where it is done.  Also, the `new/delete` gymnastics will at some point fail on you, for the simple reason that it is very easy to lose track of your logic somewhere, where you *are* deleting twice, or allocating twice without a deletion.

Comment: @SwissAndOr Also, I see `new int`.  Why?  Coding like that makes the rest of the code suspicious.  Instead of raw pointers, maybe you should invest in learning how to use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`, or if `currentShape` is shared by multiple enitities, `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie XD. My friend and I are working on this project together and I put that there as a joke (hence the TODO: YES) since that piece of code won't get executed unless we really messed up our program. Also I found the problem below. I used delete[] instead of delete accidentally. And our delete statements are followed immediately by new Shape so I think everything's fine, and I don't think that we'll have to new/delete it anywhere else anyways. Also I probably should switch to using ptr and STD::array instead of * and regular arrays. I think I'll do that tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete the debug heap checks the pointer and checks the allocated region plus some "guard" space before and after the region. It detected something wrong such as a write out of bounds. It could have happened anywhere prior to the delete step. What you must do is carefully trace and debug all access to the array looking for an error that writes outside of the array.

Comment: How would I do that if it's a class and not an array? EDIT: DAMN I just realized how stupid I am. I used delete[] instead of delete for some reason. It's supposed to be one class not an array of classes. Thanks! I guess I got lucky before and delete[] didn't cause any errors when used no something other than an array.